# Why is my segment tree unable to run in time?

Tags: python, pypy, segment-tree

I'm attempting the following problem, and after multiple submissions over many hours, I am still unable to get my solution to run in time

**The problem**
https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/339/D

**My solution**

```
def getInts():
    return [int(s) for s in input().split()]
 
class SegmentTree(object):
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.arr = arr
        self.tree_size = 2 * len(arr) - 1
        self.tree = [0] * self.tree_size
        self.build_tree(arr)
      
    def build_tree(self,arr):
        len_A = (self.tree_size+1)//2
        zz = len_A-1
        for j in range(zz,zz+len_A):
            self.tree[j] = arr[j-zz]
        flag = True
        while zz:
            zz //= 2
            len_A //= 2
            for node in range(zz,zz+len_A):
                val1 = self.tree[node*2+1]
                val2 = self.tree[node*2+2]
                if flag:
                    self.tree[node] = val1 | val2
                else:
                    self.tree[node] = val1 ^ val2
            flag = False    
            
 
    def update(self, start, value):
        len_A = (self.tree_size+1)//2
        zz = len_A-1+start
        self.tree[zz] = value
        flag = True
        while zz:
            zz -= 1
            zz //= 2
            val1 = self.tree[zz*2+1]
            val2 = self.tree[zz*2+2]
            if flag:
                self.tree[zz] = val1 | val2
            else:
                self.tree[zz] = val1 ^ val2
            flag = False
            
def solve():
    N, M = getInts()
    A = getInts()
    ttt = SegmentTree(A)
    for m in range(M):
        P, B = getInts()
        ttt.update(P-1,B)
        print(ttt.tree[0])
    return
 
solve()
```

The idea is to build a segment tree each element of the original array is a leaf, and each operation (OR or XOR alternately) is the next level up, until we reach the root of the tree.

Clearly I am not implementing something optimally, though, as it continues not to run in time for the largest inputs. Comparing my solution with others' solutions in Pypy / Python, I am completely stumped as to why mine won't run in time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After significant playing around with other people's successful solutions, I was able to make the above run by adding the following header code:

```
import sys
reader = (line.rstrip() for line in sys.stdin)
input = reader.__next__
```

I can only think that this speeds things up because it doesn't have to look up the input() method every time, but I'm really no expert on these things, and if anyone can shed further light on this then please do.

Comment: ``input()`` is a slow operation meant really more for interactive usage.  It flushes stdout, for example, even if no prompt is printed (at least in PyPy3).  It also looks for and invoke custom hooks, if any.  Replacing it with something simpler, like ``sys.stdin.readline()`` or using the hack you describe, makes it faster.